# WHERE without SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the below code to INSERT some data to my table.

It works fine without the WHERE statement, but when I try to only insert the 'Voice Calls' values it errors on the syntax. I think it is because to use WHERE I have to have a SELECT statement, but I am not sure what the SQL needs to look like

```
Dim strSql As String = 
"INSERT INTO [" + FileNameOnly + "] (Account,[From],[To],Country,[Description],ConnectTime,ChargedTime,ChargedTimeSecs,ChargedAmount,ServiceName,ChargedQuantity,ServiceUnit) 
VALUES(@Account,@From,@To,@Country,@Description,@ConnectTime,@ChargedTime,@ChargedTimeSecs,@ChargedAmount,@ServiceName,@ChargedQuantity,@ServiceUnit) 
WHERE [ServiceName] = 'Voice Calls' "
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the schema of your table?

Comment: If you only want to run the SQL when a variable has a certain value, why not add that as a conditional branch of your code to run the SQL in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

You can't do an `INSERT INTO... VALUES ... WHERE`

You can do an `INSERT INTO... VALUES`

or an `INSERT INTO... SELECT ... WHERE`

so

```
INSERT INTO TARGETTABLE 
            (FIELDA, 
             FIELDB, 
             FIELDC, 
             FIELDD) 
SELECT 'A', --some "constant" value
       'B', --some "constant" value
       'C', --some "constant" value
       SOMEFIELDSFROMYOURTABLE --a field of YOURTABLE
FROM   YOURTABLE 
WHERE  SOMECONDITION
```

But your query is maybe rather an update than an insert ?

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE 
SET    FIELDA = 'a', 
       FIELDB = 'b', 
       FIELDC = 'c', 
       FIELDD = 'd' 
WHERE  SERVICENAME = 'Voice Calls'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim strSql As String = 
"INSERT INTO [" + FileNameOnly + "] (Account,[From],[To],Country,[Description],ConnectTime,ChargedTime,ChargedTimeSecs,ChargedAmount,ServiceName,ChargedQuantity,ServiceUnit) 
SELECT *
From (Select @Account as [Account], @From as [From], ... ,@ServiceName as ServiceName, ...)z
WHERE z.[ServiceName] = 'Voice Calls' "
```